# Android broadcast event for multiple recepients

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have an async task which downloads photos from a server and updates the a field in the main data structure.

Now the user can navigate around the application without those pictures ( they are just profile pictures ). I would like to notify the currently visible activity when the download is complete in order for it to update it's UI if there is need to.

How do I do that in Android? In Django and other frameworks there are things called "signals" which is basically an inner broadcast message which then other objects can listen for, but I couldn't find similar thing in Android. Also I was thinking of implementing a BroadcastReceiver, but then I have to manually "notify" all listeners as well as have every listener manually register and unregister, which is not hard but I hope there is an easier solution.

My questions is "should I go with the BroadcastReceiver implementation or is there support already for such thing".

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) or [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should not use the Broadcast receiver only to notify at multiple places.
Instead of it there are lots of ways as you can use [otto library](http://square.github.io/otto/) and you can also follow the [observer design pattern](https://andhradroid.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/object-observer-pattern-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

BoadcastReceiver is one of the easiest way to achieve updates to UI on multitask environment.But you can also use handlers for the same ,please refer the below link it provide a very good example of different such multitask scenarios ,hope it will help.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Threads_and_Thread_Handlers_-_An_Android_Studio_Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Here is a possible solution for you:

Define an event class (you don't have to extend any class)

```
public class DownloadComplete {
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    public DownloadComplete(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }
    public void displayImage(ImageView imageView) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Call `post()` method when download completed

```
@Override
public void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new DownloadComplete(result));
}
```

Register any activity you want to receive the event

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

And implement `onEvent()` method for the activities

```
public void onEvent(DownloadComplete event) {
    // assume that you have mImage field of class ImageView in your activity
    event.displayImage(mImageView);
}
```

And that's it.